# How to get fetch data the same way as PHP with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I have this php code which gets me data as JSON string from the server. So my question is how can I do this exact thing with Javascript? I have to do all the steps including setting apikey, query and skip vertification. Also is it safe? Because PHP is server side and JS client side.

Thank you!

```
    $url = 'https://opendata.company.fi/reservation/search';
    $apiKey='xxxxxyxyxyxyxyxy:'; // required ':' after the api-key
    $query= "{
        \"startDate\":\"2014-11-22T09:00\",
        \"endDate\":\"2014-11-25T15:00\",
    \"room\":[\"X101\"]

}";
    $session = curl_init($url); // set up session
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiKey); // authentication
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query); // add query entries
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // skips verification if certificates cause problems
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // returns data as string
    $response = curl_exec($session); // execute and get response
    curl_close($session); //close session
```

Comment: is it possible to use ajax?

Comment: If you use this on the client side your API key will be visible to everybody, and everybody can (ab)use it. If you are writing a server side script, for example for usage with node.js, it will be as safe as in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [jQuery's `ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method.

However, if you use AJAX to call the API directly, you'll run into two problems: 1) ajax can't be used for cross domain requests, per most browser's [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), and 2) your API key will be exposed to the client.

You could just have your current php script return the JSON for you, and use AJAX to query it, instead of the API. Essentially you'll be wrapping the external API. That seems like the best solution.